# Simple insert/remove tag button for CKEditor 4.1

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm working on a CKEditor 4.1 integration with my site.

I'm looking for a way to replicate to the letter the look and feel of the basicstyle "B" button, but with a different tag (i need to wrap/unwrap the text in the  tag instead of ).

Right now I created a plugin with the logic

```
editor.insertHtml('<zzz>' + editor.getSelection().getNative() + '</zzz>');
```

but it can't remove the tag and I suspect there is a simpler way to obtain this.

I also experimented with

```
var format={element:'zzz'};
var style=new CKEDITOR.style(format);
style.apply(editor.document);
```

But I can't remove the forma and it sill looks a bit to clunky for a simple thing as this.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look basicstyle plugin (http://ckeditor.com/addon/basicstyles) and add your code.

Or you can found a survival pack here to write a your plugin : http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Tutorials

especially this part:

```
if ( element )
    element = element.getAscendant( 'abbr', true );

if ( !element || element.getName() != 'abbr' || element.data( 'cke-realelement' ) )
{
    element = editor.document.createElement( 'abbr' );
    this.insertMode = true;
}
else
    this.insertMode = false;
```

Check this plugin for inspiration : http://ckeditor.com/addon/insertpre

Comment: Using basicstyles as a template a was able to get what i wanted.